# Show a custom page for notfound folders

Tags: .htaccess

I want so show A custom page for example sub.php , whenever a url is not found

for example

```
http://domain.com/blabla/
http://domain.com/blabla/bladas.html
http://domain.com/tedabad/dasd/sadsad/
```

So above are all the examples of not found urls , Which I would like to display contents of  `http://domain.com/sub.php` , I tried below code , but its not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /sub.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/sub.php [L]
```

Comment: What if you disable Directory listing and use default 404 error page? :) Anyway I like your idea.

Comment: This is not for 404 :) ..This will help me creating multiple pages via database without creating new folders and files

Comment: The redneck version: create a redirect index.html (to the sub.php) and copy it to all folder and set default content the index.html. :) But hope you will solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for presence of `sub.php` in a `RewriteCond` and use an `ErrorDocument` directive:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1/sub\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/sub.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /sub.php [L]
```

Comment: It gives 404 header...I want to display as normal 200